# Retrieve "IP Phone" Attribute from AD for Exchange Disclaimer/Signature

Tags: active-directory, exchange, outlook, attributes

I'm trying to build a company-wide signature in Exchange using the Transport Rules and Disclaimers. I'd like to include our Skype names as part of this signature. In ADAC, the closest field I could find to Skype was "IP Phone" however I'm unable to find a way to retrieve it using a variable such as `%%MobileNumber%%`, `%%FirstName%%`, et al. Is there a way to retrieve this field? Also, the list I found of attributes can be found near the bottom of the page here under `ADAtrributes`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638183(v=exchg.141).aspx I don't necessarily want to jam our Skype name under "Fax Number" or something if I don't have to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this built in to Exchange without doing something like [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/exchange/customizing-the-outlook-address-book/) where they essentially are copying the values in the attribute over to an attribute that Exchange can see, in this case they used extensionAttribute1.

However, I have 2 suggestions:

1. You instead use a different field like "Pager" which should be retrievable and also shows up in the GUI Address Book details in Outlook.
2. Personally, I'd suggest using [Signature Manager](http://www.exclaimer.com/signature-manager-exchange-edition/) from Exclaimer.com.  Their solutions are excellent and fully customizable with a ton of attribute options, settings, etc.  Or you can use their Mail Disclaimers software.